Change the link for the $\LaTeX$ reference in our help center
According to this answer on the feature request "The MathJax help link should point to a more specific guide" we can change the link for our $\LaTeX$ help here to a site specific one. This is the feature request that follows the answer on that feature request.
To be precise, we would like that link to point to Using MathJax / $\TeX$ on the Cryptography site.

Feel free to leave comments on our little guide.

I think dividing the sections into answers is very useful as math did. Also, adding a table of contents in the question will be better, too.

@kelalaka I'll try and find some time to look at the Math site and split things up if I think it makes sense. I think that fgrieu is fine with editing the question text as well, but I'll ask. Maybe I should have pointed to another Q/A.

This says status-completed, but I can't find the link to the meta answer in the help center section on Latex. The only link is to mathjax.org. Am I missing something, or did the link get set to the wrong target?

This is static content, I'd wait a bit, probably cached somewhere.

Simply said, the wrong link: the formatting help (the question mark on the formatting bar above the question) was altered. Unfortunately, I don't get the same right hand side block when clicking the ? mark on answering a question, so I'll send out this request again.

I've tried to add equation numbering, I've seen that the Latex answer become too heavy to test. One might say that test an empty then insert. I still prefer to divide it into parts and give the link in the question.
